# NASM Length of an Argument

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, nasm

I am writing a simple program to display a name supplied by the user.  The result is that I should be able to enter the command and get the expected result.

**Command**

```
./hello John
```

**Result**

```
Hello, John.
```

Yet when the program gets around to displaying the name, it doesn't.  I believe it has something to do with calculating the length of the argument.  May you guys please take a look at my code and tell me what you think?

```
; hello.asm
;
; Assemble: nasm -f elf hello.asm
; Link:     ld -o hello hello.o
; Run:      ./hello <name>

section .data
    period:      db  ".", 10
    periodLen:   equ $-period

    helloMsg:    db  "Hello, "
    helloMsgLen: equ $-helloMsg

    usageMsg:    db  "Usage: hello <name>", 10
    usageMsgLen: equ $-usageMsg

section .text
    global _start

_start:
    pop eax                     ; Get number of arguments
    cmp eax, 2                  ; If one argument
    jne _help                   ; Not equal, show help + exit

    mov eax, 4                  ; System call to write
    mov ebx, 1                  ; Write to console
    mov ecx, helloMsg           ; Display "Hello, "
    mov edx, helloMsgLen        ; Length of hello message
    int 80h

    mov eax, 4                  ; System call to write
    mov ebx, 1                  ; Write to console
    pop ecx                     ; Get program name
    pop ecx                     ; Get name
    mov edx, $                  ; Beginning of line
    sub edx, ecx                ; Get length of name
    int 80h

    mov eax, 4                  ; System call to write
    mov ebx, 1                  ; Write to console
    mov ecx, period             ; Display a period
    mov edx, periodLen          ; Length of period
    int 80h

    mov eax, 1                  ; System call to exit
    mov ebx, 0                  ; No errors
    int 80h

_help:
    mov eax, 4                  ; System call to write
    mov ebx, 1                  ; Write to console
    mov ecx, usageMsg           ; Display usage message
    mov edx, usageMsgLen        ; Length of usage message
    int 80h

    mov eax, 1                  ; System call to exit
    mov ebx, 0                  ; No errors
    int 80h
```

Comment: does it print "hello, "?

Comment: Yes, the final output is "Hello, ."

Comment: perhaps `ecx` contains garbage. try looking to what does it point to with a debugger

Comment: I've never used a debugger before. So any advice? /:P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, since you never used a debugger, I'll show you how. First, compile with `nasm -f elf -g hello.asm`. The `-g` switch helps the debugger, this way you can set breakpoints etc. Now start it typing `gdb ./hello -q` and type `break 34`. This tells `gdb` to stop at line 34. Run the program (type `run emi` (emi is my name :P)). You should see something like this:

```
blackbear@blackbear-laptop:~$ gdb ./hello -q
Reading symbols from /home/blackbear/hello...done.
(gdb) break 34
Breakpoint 1 at 0x80480a9: file hello.asm, line 34.
(gdb) run emi
Starting program: /home/blackbear/hello emi
Hello, 
Breakpoint 1, _start () at hello.asm:34
34      pop ecx                     ; Get name
(gdb)
```

Ok, let's see what `ecx` is, typing `display (char *) $ecx`:

```
(gdb) display (char *) $ecx
1: (char *) $ecx = 0xbffff63e "/home/blackbear/hello"
```

You can use `step` to continue by one instruction:

```
(gdb) step
35      mov edx, $                  ; Beginning of line
1: (char *) $ecx = 0xbffff654 "emi"
```

Ok, here we are. `ecx` points to my name, so the problem isn't here. Now we don't need to watch `ecx` anymore, so using `undisplay` `gdb` won't show it anymore. But we need to check `edx`:

```
(gdb) undisplay
Delete all auto-display expressions? (y or n) y
(gdb) display $edx
2: $edx = 7
(gdb) step
36      sub edx, ecx                ; Get length of name
2: $edx = 134512810
(gdb) step
37      int 80h
2: $edx = 1208257110
```

Mmh, guess you didn't expect this, right? :) The problem seems to be here: `mov edx, $`. I don't get that `$` (never used NASM), could you please explain?

**EDIT**
Ok got it. You misunderstood what the tutorial said. The `$` represents the *current* location of it, in fact:

```
36      sub edx, ecx                ; Get length of name
11: $edx = 134512810
(gdb) display (void *) $edx
12: (void *) $edx = (void *) 0x80480aa
(gdb) display (void *) $eip
13: (void *) $eip = (void *) 0x80480af
```

now `edx` contains the address of the instruction `mov edx, $`. which is 5 bytes long (opcode (1 byte) + address (4 bytes)), that's why `eip - edx = 5`.
In order to get the length of the argument your only way is to use something like `strlen()`, but I can't help you here, NASM isn't my assembler. :)

Comment: I read the tutorial at http://www.cin.ufpe.br/~if817/arquivos/asmtut/index.html#advanced; and it said that when NASM sees $ it replaces it with the assembly position at the beginning of the line.  Almost like saying mov edx, $-ecx